# What is the default Ubuntu Server 22.04 network renderer?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

This is a clean, default Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 LTS install and I have changed no actual network settings, only ssh configuration. Does my system use `networkd` or `NetworkManager` by default? I do not understand the relation between them.

I've been learning and using Ubuntu in a homelab environment (dedicated physical server, not virtual). I've spent some time trying to get answers both on stackexchange and other places trying to get a straight answer to no avail. Ubuntu apparently comes with both installed, there's a netplan yaml file called `00-installer-config.yaml` (although apparently other people having something else by default? ex: 01netcfg.yaml). However the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory is empty and nmcli shows my nic to be unmanaged.

Both `NetworkManager` and `systemd-networkd` services are running.

Comment: My Ubuntu server doesn't even have Network Manager installed. Did you install a desktop?

Comment: no, I downloaded the Server LTS 22.04.1 directly, which is installed to be headless by default

Comment: That's...odd. My server is 20.04, but I'm surprised they would make such a change for 22.04

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: "*I do not understand the relation between them.*" Oversimplification: NetworkManager is designed for user choice of interfaces, like connecting to a new WiFi network, or choosing between multiple connections. networkd is designed for interfaces and connections that are consistent and unchanging. NetworkManger is not included in a stock install of Ubuntu Server 22.04, since servers generally do not have frequently-changing interfaces. If you really do have both installed, the network renderer will be whatever you specified in your Netplan YAML.